# SOAP with custom form select

Tags: forms

I'm getting results from a SOAP call, but cannot display the values in a  select list on my custom module.
This is a part of my code:

```
foreach($sxml2->NewDataSet->DepCity as $item) {
    $fromName = $item->Name;     
    echo '<li>' . $fromName . '</li>'; //It displays correctly  


    $form['from'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => t('From'),
        '#options' => $fromName, 
    );      
}
```

$sxml2 is a simplexml load string result and it's display correctly.
When I echo the result from the loop ($fromName), I'm getting all the strings properly, but If I try to put that variable in a custom form select, it doesn't display any data.

How can I get the results in a Drupal form select?

EDIT:

I've tried with this, but it still doesn't display anything in that select.

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($sxml2); //The whole simpleXML object with arrays is displaying properly    
echo '</pre>';


$options = array();
foreach($sxml2->NewDataSet->DepCity as $item) {
  $options[$item->Name] = $item->Name;
  echo '<li>' . $item->Name . '</li>'; //It displays correctly  

}

$form['from'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('From'),
  '#options' => $options, //It doesn't display the data
);
```

Answer (score 0):

The `#options` property should be an array of key value pairs (the *key* is the `<option>`'s `value` attribute, the *value* is the content of that tag), so:

```
$options = array();
foreach($sxml2->NewDataSet->DepCity as $item) {
  $options[$item->Name] = $item->Name;
}

$form['from'] = array(
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => t('From'),
  '#options' => $options,
);
```

That's just for demonstration, you may wish to use something other than a name for the option key - it's the sort of thing that would clash easily.

Comment: Hi, Clive. I've tried with your example, but it still doesn't display anything. I've tried as a test with $test = array(1,2,3); and set that array in options and it's displays the data, so I don't have any problem with the form. It just doesn't display the data from SOAP inside that form. I've edited my thread.